# Java: Listen For Second KeyPress

Tags: java, swing, keypress, keylistener, keyevent

I have a list of colors with numbers associated with them. I'd like to make it so that, if the user types in "2", it selects "2: Green"; if they type in "21", it selects "21: Yellow"; etc. I'm trying to use KeyPressed, and I think I need some way for the program to listen for the first number pressed and then wait a second to see if another is pressed. For example, something like this:

```
// The integer pressed will always be zero or positive.
private void jComboBox1KeyPressed(KeyEvent evt) {
    int code = -1;

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if (evt.getKeyCode() == i) {
            if (code == -1) {
                code = i;
            } else {
                code += i;
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    // PSEUDO-CODE: if (KeyEvent newEvt is pressed within 1 sec) {
        jComboBox1KeyPressed(newEvt);
    }
}
```

Then, I suppose I'd have a key-value map with an index and the color numbers, and I'd set the selected item for `jComboBox1` based on `code` (the selected color number).

I've got it working for a single keyPressed:

```
private void jComboBox1KeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                      
    if (evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_0) {
        jComboBox1.setSelectedItem("2: Green");
    }
    else if (evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_1) {
        jComboBox1.setSelectedItem("21: Yellow");
    }
    else if (evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_2) {
        jComboBox1.setSelectedItem("13: Blue");
    }
    else if (evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_3) {
        jComboBox1.setSelectedItem("2041: Red");
    }
}
```

Here's the interface:

[image: app interface]

PLEASE NOTE: This is an example I quickly made and not the actual app I'm creating. My app involves many more number options, but as with this example, the numbers will always be positive.

Comment: Have you taken a look at the [KeySelectionManager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.KeySelectionManager.html)? Here's an [example of it being used](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/ListeningtoKeyboardEventswithaKeySelectionManager.htm).

Comment: `if the user types in "2", it selects "2: Green"; if they type in "21", it selects "21: Yellow";` This is the default behaviour of a JComboBox. No need for any special code. If you type multiple characters in a certain time frame the item with those characters will be selected. If you have having trouble with this, then post an [mcve] demonstrating the problem.

Comment: @Obicere I'm not sure this shows my issue. The example only shows a jComboBox using single characters instead of multiple.

Comment: @camickr This would be great, except that sometimes the "OK" button is highlighted, and the jComboBox would need to be highlighted in order for your suggestion to work.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. Of course focus needs to be on the combo box in order for an item in the combo box to be selected. This is the way all swing components work. If you want text to be entered in a text field, then focus needs to be on the text field, not a button. And you haven't posted an [mcve] so there is no more help we can give.

Comment: What I mean is that I need a solution which will work no matter where the focus is. I am willing to add keypresses to both the button and the jcombobox if necessary. I can't use binding because I'm using netbeans.

Comment: `I need a solution which will work no matter where the focus is.` - that is NOT the way a GUI works. The combo box is changed when it has focus. The "OK" button is used to close the dialog once the item has been selected. Don't mix functionality of the OK button with functionality of the combo box.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks!